# How to optimize a CRON Job on Vercel that is timing out with 504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT error due to serverless function exceeding the 10 secs timeout limit

Tags: mongoose, next.js, cron, twilio, vercel

I have a CRON Job running on Vercel. But whenever I try to run it I get 504: **GATEWAY_TIMEOUT** error. I checked Logs of my Cron Job function on Vercel, and everything seems fine. So I went ahead and did some research on 504 status code and I came to know that it indicates that serverless function is taking too long to respond.Vercel has a timeout limit of 10 seconds for serverless functions. So I need to optimize this code in such a way that it executes within 10seconds timeframe.Please do suggest an optimized code.

```
import dbconnection from "@/lib/dbconn";
import Birthday from "@/models/Birthday";

dbconnection()
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    try {
        const query = Birthday.find({ date: new Date() }).lean();
        const birthdays = await query.exec();
        for (const birthday of birthdays) {
            const client = twilio(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
            const message = await client.messages.create({
                messagingServiceSid: 'MG19c8d8f851ee2e2525446fc35d1667ab',
                body: `Subramanya, Today is ${birthday.name}'s Birthday!. Don't Forget to wish`,
                from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
                to: process.env.MY_NUMBER,
            });
            console.log(`Sent message to Subramanya's Number at ${birthday.date}: ${message.sid}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Brief explaination of Code:- I am connecting to the database(MongoDB) and then querying data from birthdays collection and checking a condition, If the condition meets I am sending a message using Twillio.This is a nextJS code and I am using mongoose as my driver.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE2BF.png)
[Vercel Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohg7d.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You got a `504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT error` because you are not returning a response. you have to return a response using `res.send()`.
Also, you can modify your code below like. so that your function execution quickly.

```
import dbconnection from "@/lib/dbconn";
import Birthday from "@/models/Birthday";

dbconnection()
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    try {
        await Birthday.find({ date: new Date() }).lean().then(async(birthdays)=>{
          for (const birthday of birthdays) {
              const client = twilio(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
              const message = await client.messages.create({
                  messagingServiceSid: 'MG19c8d8f851ee2e2525446fc35d1667ab',
                  body: `Subramanya, Today is ${birthday.name}'s Birthday!. Don't Forget to wish`,
                  from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
                  to: process.env.MY_NUMBER,
              });
              console.log(`Sent message to Subramanya's Number at ${birthday.date}: ${message.sid}`);
          }
        });
        res.send({message: "All message sent successfully."})
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```